# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionE xception: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown

Tags: mysql, transactions, jboss, wildfly, connection-timeout

I have a WildFly application running on an AWS EC2 instance which is connected to MySQL database and is installed on another EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet. The connectivity between these instances is perfectly made and the application is working fine with a proper connection to the database instance.

However, upon a specific API execution, we see the below expectation in the server log which eventually leads to the failure of execution. I'm unsure what is the problem as the application is running fine and was even fine with the specific API. We have started seeing this expectation only in the last few days. The connectivity between these two instances is perfectly made without any issues.

Help me with the direction in which I need to start the debugging. We haven't made any changes to database properties lately.

Exception:

*2024-01-03 09:37:29,211 WARN [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] (default task-4350) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@64e864b[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@5fed54bf connection handles=1 lastReturned=1704254772312 lastValidated=1704253893776 lastCheckedOut=1704254772349 trackByTx=true pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@1433812f mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@98d4f08[pool=wooqDataSource] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@19fdf2dc[connectionListener=64e864b connectionManager=3faa0fba warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=5.7.30-log jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/WooqerDS] txSync=TransactionSynchronization@1451402909{tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a400c15:77ad8b58:6592d3a3:1bcf42e status: ActionStatus.COMMITTING >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider) wasTrackByTx=true enlisted=true cancel=false}]: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during commit(). Transaction resolution unknown.*

My database timeout properties are configured as below:

*connect_timeout    10
delayed_insert_timeout  300
have_statement_timeout  YES
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  ON
interactive_timeout 200
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
net_read_timeout    3600
net_write_timeout   3600
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
slave_net_timeout   60
wait_timeout    1200*